# Hibernate fails to formulate / generate a correct SQL query, when functions are used especially in conditional expressions

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Given the following criteria query :

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<UserTable> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(UserTable.class);
Root<UserTable> root = criteriaQuery.from(entityManager.getMetamodel().entity(UserTable.class));

ParameterExpression<String> parameterExpression = criteriaBuilder.parameter(String.class);
criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(criteriaBuilder.lower(criteriaBuilder.trim(root.get(UserTable_.emailId))), criteriaBuilder.lower(criteriaBuilder.trim(parameterExpression))));
List<UserTable> list = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).setParameter(parameterExpression, emailId).getResultList();
```

The query uses functions like `lower()` and `trim()`.

---

Unlike EclipseLink, the test case fails to generate correct SQL query using Hibernate 5.0.4 final. The wrongly generated SQL query is shown below.

```sql
 select
     usertable0_.user_id as user_id1_34_,
     usertable0_.email_id as email_id5_34_,
     usertable0_.first_name as first_na7_34_,
     usertable0_.middle_name as middle_12_34_,
     usertable0_.last_name as last_na11_34_,
 from
     projectdb.user_table usertable0_ 
 where
     lower(trim(BOTH 
 from
     usertable0_.email_id))=lower(trim(BOTH 
 from
     ?))
```

<sub>No exception is thrown in this case.</sub>

The issue was [reported](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5676) a long time ago during the Hibernate 3.6.0 era but it was rejected due to a lack of at lest one reproducible test case. Therefore, it is still to be fixed.

> Bulk rejecting issues lacking a test case or recent response.

Is there any work around to the issue? Means that can this query be rewritten without affecting the result set being returned?

I am using Hibernate 5.0.4 final as stated along the way.

Comment: Uh! There is nothing wrong in the generated SQL query. The hassle caused is therefore deeply regretted, sorry - made out for the first time. (EclipseLink generates `WHERE (LOWER(TRIM(email_id)) = LOWER(TRIM(?)))`. Comparing both of them at a glance, I could not observe the difference).

Comment: The server nevertheless logs a warning message as reported there on the tracker : `WARN  [org.hibernate.dialect.function.TemplateRenderer] (default task-7) HHH000174: Function template anticipated 4 arguments, but 3 arguments encountered`